# Using modular arithmetic to find$ [2^{16}]_8$...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a fairly simple problem. Just wanted to check if there's another method that I should of used. Here goes---

The problem:

> Find $2^{16} \mod 8$

So I figured this one out pretty quickly, I'm just not sure if this was done as it needed to be done.

I first re-wrote our problem as an equivalence class $[2^{16}]_8$. This is what followed
$$[2^{16}]_8 = [2^{15}\cdot 2]_8 = [2^{15}]_8[2]_8 = [(2^3)^5]_8[2]_8 = [0]_8[2]_8 = [0]_8$$
$$\implies [2^{16}]_8 = [0]_8$$
$$\implies 2^{16} \equiv 0 \mod 8$$

So my overall question is: was what I did sufficient or is there another method that is generally advisable? I feel like it's sufficient...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly sufficient, but an even easier way would be as follows:

$2^{16} = 2^3 \cdot 2^{13} = 8 \cdot 2^{13}$.

Hence the remainder when $8$ divides $2^{16}$ is $0$ and we get the desired result.

Comment: 21 seconds quicker, heh :P nice job :D

Comment: Oh whoa. Yeah that is definitely faster haha. Thanks for clearing up my suspicions :)

Answer (score 3):

This looks good, although you could have done this quicker by noting that
$$
2^{16} = 2^3 \cdot 2^{13} \equiv 0 \cdot 2^{13} \equiv 0 \pmod{8}
$$

Comment: Considering both you and Austin provided the same answer, if only I could declare both of your answers as Best Answer... :(

Comment: @SavageHenry go with Austin, he was first ;D Although, in my opinion modular arithmetic problems are best looked at through the lens of finding the remainder when dividing out by $n$ (where $n$ is what is being modded out by). So here the first thing I noticed was that $2^16 = 16 \cdot 1024$ since for some reason I just recognize $2^16$ bytes is $16$ kilobytes and thus clearly $8$ divides $16$ evenly so it's equal to $0$ (note it probably isn't standard to know $2^16$ bytes is $16$ kilobytes, I'm just crazy like that ;D)